# How can I show first and end values in Chart objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, charts, ios-charts

I'm using ios-chart ([ios Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts)). I have some values to show xAxis, but when I load a type of graph, I only want show 2 or 3 values. The first, the mid and the last value.

But i only can show 1 value at first if the values are more than 30 aprox.

I think I need override the stringForValue function, how can override this to show almost one value at finish and at begining?

```
- (NSString *)stringForValue:(double)value
                        axis:(ChartAxisBase *)axis
```

I set values array in format like:

```
xValuess: (
    "1",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "65",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "140"
)
```

But the values received in the function override islike format: 0, 50, 100. I don't know how to get the concret values of my xValues array.

Answer (score 0):

1- First you need to add <**IChartValueFormatter**>

2- Then you should set your **LineChartDataSet**'s **valueFormatter** to **self**

```
set1.valueFormatter = self;
```

3- And finally you can reach your data from;

```
-(NSString *)stringForValue:(double)value entry:(ChartDataEntry *)entry dataSetIndex:(NSInteger)dataSetIndex viewPortHandler:(ChartViewPortHandler *)viewPortHandler{
if (entry.x == 0 || entry.x == myArray.count-1) {
    NSInteger index = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:value].integerValue;
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)index];
} else {
    return @"";
}
}
```

I hope it helps.